# Mysql Equivalent of php metaphone and soundex

Tags: mysql, soundex, metaphone

I am working on an app where user's current playing song title is fetched and we look in the mysql database to see who else is playing a similar song.since the same song might be with many varied titles on everyone's phone , we need a way to effectively find as close results as possible.

The process that we are using right now gets all the songs from the table then do a foreach and compare each entry in the resultset with user's song.
Here is a part of the function we have used:

```
$all_results = $db->select($sql);//all db entries from the songs table

foreach ( $all_results as $u ) {
$toTest = strtolower( $u['last_song'] );
$toTest = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', ' ', $toTest);
$score = 0; 
$score = $this->calSim( $user_last_song, $toTest, 0 ); //user last song is the current song being played by the user
if ( $score > 1 ) { //if at least there is some match then compare by another method
    $score = $this->calMetaphone($user_last_song, $toTest, $score);
}
if ( $score > 5 ) {
    //song matches.Push into a final array
}
 }
```

=======================================

here are the 2 custom functions:

```
public function calMetaphone ( $x, $y, $pts ) {
     $x = metaphone( $x );
     $y = metaphone( $y );
     $pts = $this->calSim( $x, $y, $pts );
     return $pts;
}
public function calSim ( $x, $y, $pts ) {
     similar_text($x, $y, $sim);
     //echo "Similarity is :$sim<br>";
     if ( $sim >= 90 ) {
         $pts = $pts + 5;
     } else if ( $sim >= 80 ) {
         $pts = $pts + 4;
     }
     if ( $sim >= 70 ) {
         $pts = $pts + 3;
     }
     if ( $sim >= 60 ) {
         $pts = $pts + 2;
     } else {
         $pts = $pts + 0;
     }
     return $pts;
  }
```

But I know this is a real bad way of doing it.If there are large number of entries in database it might take forever to compare them all 1 by 1.

Can anyone tell me the correct method that should be followed here.

Thanks
Karam

Comment: I think you'll need to give some details about the `calSim` and `calMetaphone` functions. They don't seem to be standard PHP.

Comment: MySQL has `SOUNDEX()`, you can select like `"SELECT FROM table WHERE SOUNDEX(columnSongName) LIKE SOUNDEX('" . $currentSongName . "')"`

Comment: the 2 functions have been added to the description.Mysql SOUNDEX is good for a single word string , but it will not give accurate results for a sentence.

Comment: Still looking for a correct solution.Really need this ASAP.Right now I have showed the client a working demo of the App , but I know as database will grow , things will begin to die.Is there anyway I can optimize my logic? Else I ll have to continue with this I think.

Answer (score 3):

I can't take any credit for this but when I needed a similar function I found this (can't remember where though) for a metaphone:-

```
DROP FUNCTION `func_Double_Metaphone`//
CREATE DEFINER=`aaaa`@`%` FUNCTION `func_Double_Metaphone`(st VARCHAR(55)) RETURNS varchar(128) CHARSET utf8
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE length, first, last, pos, prevpos, is_slavo_germanic SMALLINT;
    DECLARE pri, sec VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE ch CHAR(1);
                    SET first = 3;
    SET length = CHAR_LENGTH(st);
    SET last = first + length -1;
    SET st = CONCAT(REPEAT('-', first -1), UCASE(st), REPEAT(' ', 5));  SET is_slavo_germanic = (st LIKE '%W%' OR st LIKE '%K%' OR st LIKE '%CZ%');     SET pos = first;        IF SUBSTRING(st, first, 2) IN ('GN', 'KN', 'PN', 'WR', 'PS') THEN
        SET pos = pos + 1;
    END IF;
        IF SUBSTRING(st, first, 1) = 'X' THEN
        SET pri = 'S', sec = 'S', pos = pos  + 1;   END IF;
        WHILE pos <= last DO
            SET prevpos = pos;
        SET ch = SUBSTRING(st, pos, 1);         CASE
        WHEN ch IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') THEN
            IF pos = first THEN                 SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'A'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'A'), pos = pos  + 1;             ELSE
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'B' THEN
                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'B' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'P'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'P'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'P'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'P'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'C' THEN
                        IF (pos > (first + 1) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 1) NOT IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 3) = 'ACH' AND
               (SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) NOT IN ('I', 'E') OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 6) IN ('BACHER', 'MACHER'))) THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;                         ELSEIF pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 6) = 'CAESAR' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) = 'CHIA' THEN              SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'CH' THEN
                                IF pos > first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) = 'CHAE' THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 2;                 ELSEIF pos = first AND (SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 5) IN ('HARAC', 'HARIS') OR
                   SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 3) IN ('HOR', 'HYM', 'HIA', 'HEM')) AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 5) != 'CHORE' THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;                                 ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, first, 4) IN ('VAN ', 'VON ') OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 3) = 'SCH'
                   OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 6) IN ('ORCHES', 'ARCHIT', 'ORCHID')
                   OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) IN ('T', 'S')
                   OR ((SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) IN ('A', 'O', 'U', 'E') OR pos = first)
                   AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) IN ('L', 'R', 'N', 'M', 'B', 'H', 'F', 'V', 'W', ' ')) THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;                 ELSE
                    IF pos > first THEN
                        IF SUBSTRING(st, first, 2) = 'MC' THEN
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;                         ELSE
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;                         END IF;
                    ELSE
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 2;                     END IF;
                END IF;
                        ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'CZ' AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 4) != 'WICZ' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 2;                         ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 3) = 'CIA' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3;                         ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'CC' AND NOT (pos = (first +1) AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 1) = 'M') THEN
                                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) IN ('I', 'E', 'H') AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 2) != 'HU' THEN
                                        IF (pos = first +1 AND SUBSTRING(st, first) = 'A') OR
                       SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 5) IN ('UCCEE', 'UCCES') THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'KS'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'KS'), pos = pos  + 3;                                       ELSE
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3;                     END IF;
                ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;                 END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) IN ('CK', 'CG', 'CQ') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) IN ('CI', 'CE', 'CY') THEN
                                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 3) IN ('CIO', 'CIE', 'CIA') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 2;                 ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 2;                 END IF;
            ELSE 
                                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) IN (' C', ' Q', ' G') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 3;                 ELSE
                    IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('C', 'K', 'Q') AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) NOT IN ('CE', 'CI') THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;                     ELSE                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 1;                     END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
                            WHEN ch = 'D' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'DG' THEN
                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) IN ('I', 'E', 'Y') THEN                  SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 3;                 ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'TK'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'TK'), pos = pos  + 2;               END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) IN ('DT', 'DD') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'T'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'T'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'F' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'F' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'G' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'H' THEN
                IF (pos > first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) NOT IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y')) 
                    OR ( pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) != 'I') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;                 ELSEIF pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) = 'I' THEN
                     SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 2;                                ELSEIF (pos > (first + 1) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 1) IN ('B', 'H', 'D') )
                   OR (pos > (first + 2) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-3, 1) IN ('B', 'H', 'D') )
                   OR (pos > (first + 3) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-4, 1) IN ('B', 'H') ) THEN
                    SET pos = pos + 2;              ELSE
                                        IF pos > (first + 2) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) = 'U'
                       AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-3, 1) IN ('C', 'G', 'L', 'R', 'T') THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 2;                     ELSEIF pos > first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) != 'I' THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;           ELSE
              SET pos = pos + 1;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'N' THEN
                IF pos = (first +1) AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') AND NOT is_slavo_germanic THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'KN'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'N'), pos = pos  + 2;                ELSE
                                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 2) != 'EY' AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) != 'Y'
                        AND NOT is_slavo_germanic THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'N'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'KN'), pos = pos  + 2;                    ELSE
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'KN'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'KN'), pos = pos  + 2;                   END IF;
                END IF;
                        ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) = 'LI' AND NOT is_slavo_germanic THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'KL'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'L'), pos = pos  + 2;                        ELSEIF pos = first AND (SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Y'
               OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) IN ('ES', 'EP', 'EB', 'EL', 'EY', 'IB', 'IL', 'IN', 'IE', 'EI', 'ER')) THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 2;                         ELSEIF (SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) = 'ER' OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Y')
               AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 6) NOT IN ('DANGER', 'RANGER', 'MANGER')
               AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) not IN ('E', 'I') AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 3) NOT IN ('RGY', 'OGY') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 2;                         ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('E', 'I', 'Y') OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 4) IN ('AGGI', 'OGGI') THEN
                                IF SUBSTRING(st, first, 4) IN ('VON ', 'VAN ') OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 3) = 'SCH'
                   OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 2) = 'ET' THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;                 ELSE
                                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 4) = 'IER ' THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 2;                     ELSE
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;                     END IF;
                END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'G' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'H' THEN
                        IF (pos = first OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y')) 
                AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'H'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'H'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE                SET pos = pos + 1;          END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'J' THEN
                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) = 'JOSE' OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 4) = 'SAN ' THEN
                IF (pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+4, 1) = ' ') OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 4) = 'SAN ' THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'H'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'H');                 ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'H');                 END IF;
            ELSEIF pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) != 'JOSE' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'A');             ELSE
                                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') AND NOT is_slavo_germanic
                   AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('A', 'O') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'H');                 ELSE
                    IF pos = last THEN
                        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J');                     ELSE
                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) not IN ('L', 'T', 'K', 'S', 'N', 'M', 'B', 'Z')
                           AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) not IN ('S', 'K', 'L') THEN
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J');                         END IF;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'J' THEN
                SET pos = pos + 2;
            ELSE
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'K' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'K' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'L' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'L' THEN
                                IF (pos = (last - 2) AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 4) IN ('ILLO', 'ILLA', 'ALLE'))
                   OR ((SUBSTRING(st, last-1, 2) IN ('AS', 'OS') OR SUBSTRING(st, last) IN ('A', 'O'))
                   AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 4) = 'ALLE') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'L'), pos = pos  + 2;                 ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'L'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'L'), pos = pos  + 2;                 END IF;
            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'L'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'L'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'M' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 3) = 'UMB'
               AND (pos + 1 = last OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 2) = 'ER')
               OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'M' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'M'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'M'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'M'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'M'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'N' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'N' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'N'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'N'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'N'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'N'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
                            WHEN ch = 'P' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'H' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('P', 'B') THEN               SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'P'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'P'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'P'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'P'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'Q' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Q' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'K'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'K'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'R' THEN
                        IF pos = last AND not is_slavo_germanic
               AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 2) = 'IE' AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-4, 2) NOT IN ('ME', 'MA') THEN
                SET sec = CONCAT(sec, 'R');             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'R'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'R');             END IF;
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'R' THEN
                SET pos = pos + 2;
            ELSE
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'S' THEN
                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 3) IN ('ISL', 'YSL') THEN
                SET pos = pos + 1;
                        ELSEIF pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, first, 5) = 'SUGAR' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 1;             ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'SH' THEN
                                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 4) IN ('HEIM', 'HOEK', 'HOLM', 'HOLZ') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 2;                 ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 2;                 END IF;
                        ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 3) IN ('SIO', 'SIA') OR SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) = 'SIAN' THEN
                IF NOT is_slavo_germanic THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3;                 ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 3;                 END IF;
                                    ELSEIF (pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('M', 'N', 'L', 'W')) OR SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Z' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X');                 IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Z' THEN
                    SET pos = pos + 2;
                ELSE
                    SET pos = pos + 1;
                END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'SC' THEN
                                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) = 'H' THEN
                                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+3, 2) IN ('OO', 'ER', 'EN', 'UY', 'ED', 'EM') THEN
                                                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+3, 2) IN ('ER', 'EN') THEN
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'SK'), pos = pos  + 3;                        ELSE
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'SK'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'SK'), pos = pos  + 3;                       END IF;
                    ELSE
                        IF pos = first AND SUBSTRING(st, first+3, 1) not IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') AND SUBSTRING(st, first+3, 1) != 'W' THEN
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 3;                         ELSE
                            SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3;                         END IF;
                    END IF;
                ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 1) IN ('I', 'E', 'Y') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 3;                 ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'SK'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'SK'), pos = pos  + 3;               END IF;
                        ELSEIF pos = last AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 2) IN ('AI', 'OI') THEN
                SET sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S'), pos = pos  + 1;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S');                 IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('S', 'Z') THEN
                    SET pos = pos + 2;
                ELSE
                    SET pos = pos + 1;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'T' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) = 'TION' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3;             ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 3) IN ('TIA', 'TCH') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'X'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'X'), pos = pos  + 3;             ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'TH' OR SUBSTRING(st, pos, 3) = 'TTH' THEN
                                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+2, 2) IN ('OM', 'AM') OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 4) IN ('VON ', 'VAN ')
                   OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 3) = 'SCH' THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'T'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 2;                 ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, '0'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 2;                 END IF;
            ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('T', 'D') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'T'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'T'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'T'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'V' THEN
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'V' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'F'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 1;             END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'W' THEN
                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'WR' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'R'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'R'), pos = pos  + 2;             ELSEIF pos = first AND (SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y')
                OR SUBSTRING(st, pos, 2) = 'WH') THEN
                                IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y') THEN
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'A'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 1;                 ELSE
                    SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'A'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'A'), pos = pos  + 1;                 END IF;
                        ELSEIF (pos = last AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y'))
               OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 5) IN ('EWSKI', 'EWSKY', 'OWSKI', 'OWSKY')
               OR SUBSTRING(st, first, 3) = 'SCH' THEN
                SET sec = CONCAT(sec, 'F'), pos = pos  + 1;                                     ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos, 4) IN ('WICZ', 'WITZ') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'TS'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'FX'), pos = pos  + 4;           ELSE                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'X' THEN
                        IF not(pos = last AND (SUBSTRING(st, pos-3, 3) IN ('IAU', 'EAU')
               OR SUBSTRING(st, pos-2, 2) IN ('AU', 'OU'))) THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'KS'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'KS');           END IF;
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) IN ('C', 'X') THEN
                SET pos = pos + 2;
            ELSE
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        WHEN ch = 'Z' THEN
                        IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'H' THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'J'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'J'), pos = pos  + 1;             ELSEIF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 3) IN ('ZO', 'ZI', 'ZA')
               OR (is_slavo_germanic AND pos > first AND SUBSTRING(st, pos-1, 1) != 'T') THEN
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'TS');            ELSE
                SET pri = CONCAT(pri, 'S'), sec = CONCAT(sec, 'S');             END IF;
            IF SUBSTRING(st, pos+1, 1) = 'Z' THEN
                SET pos = pos + 2;
            ELSE
                SET pos = pos + 1;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            SET pos = pos + 1;      END CASE;
    IF pos = prevpos THEN
       SET pos = pos +1;
       SET pri = CONCAT(pri,'<didnt incr>');     END IF;
    END WHILE;
    IF pri != sec THEN
        SET pri = CONCAT(pri, ';', sec);
  END IF;
    RETURN (pri);
END
```

I also needed a levenshtein function and managed to sort out one of those, but performance was such (when comparing values from many rows) that it was far faster to read the rows and use the php built in levenshtein function.

Comment: We had to finally change the approach.We are now using audio fingerprinting to match the sounds rather than the titles.

Comment: In order for this to work now, we need to add `DELIMITER $$` at the start (just before the function declaration), finish the function declaration with `END$$` instead of just `END` and then reset the delimiter to `DELIMITER ;` at the very end (after the function declaration).