# Mysql Soundex Query How Can I Take Best Result

Tags: mysql, soundex

Mysql query and results are this img.

http://i.hizliresim.com/6JoaNv.jpg

> select * FROM kelimekontrol  WHERE SOUNDEX(kelime) = SOUNDEX('ağde')

i think it is the best result of ağda words but idont get this result.

how can i improve best result for this

thanks

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/6JoaNv.jpg isn't accessible. Error: 403 Forbidden
Request forbidden by administrative rules.

Comment: https://ibb.co/d8pAr7

Comment: Let's face it, sounded is a lousy algorithm.

Comment: yes it's a terrible algorithm, but we have it :) how can we improve this algorithm. so how can I at least give the nearest result in sorting?

Comment: from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like 
- This function, as currently implemented, is intended to work well with strings that are in the English language only. Strings in other languages may not produce reliable results.
- This function is not guaranteed to provide consistent results with strings that use multibyte character sets, including utf-8. See Bug #22638 for more information.

Comment: Maybe checking out of MySQL with PHP or Pyhton. Otherwise soemthing like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374514/mysql-equivalent-of-php-metaphone-and-soundex